# Which Open Graph type should be used for product overview pages

Tags: open-graph-protocol

What is the Open Graph type I should use for product overview pages?
E.g. `example.com/laptops` which shows a number of laptops.

I already use Open Graph metadata per product on this page, but if someone shares the overview page to for example Facebook, I still want to have a category image, description, title AND the correct Open Graph type.

Can I just use `product` as the type? Not sure what to use from the available list here http://ogp.me/#types